# What does $\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla$ mean here?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, differentiation, notation, vector-fields

What does $\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla$ mean in an expression like $(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf B$?

I found this in Griffiths’ *Classical Electrodynamics* book and cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 7):

$$\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla=A_x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ A_y\frac{\partial}{\partial y} + A_z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$$

because it is the dot product of

$$\mathbf A=A_x\hat x+A_y\hat y+A_z\hat z$$

and

$$\nabla=\hat x\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+\hat y\frac{\partial}{\partial y}+\hat z\frac{\partial}{\partial z}.$$

So $\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla$ is a scalar differential operator that, in the case of $(\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf B$, acts on each component of $\mathbf B$ to produce a new vector.

You can think of it as a form of “directional derivative”, measuring how rapidly something changes in space along the vector $\mathbf A$. The usual directional derivative in the direction $\hat{\mathbf n}$ is $\hat{\mathbf n}\cdot\nabla$, where $\hat{\mathbf n}$ is a unit vector. So $\mathbf{A}\cdot\nabla$ is the product of the directional derivative in the direction of $\mathbf A$ and the magnitude of $\mathbf A$.